# openURL fails with Settings Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, uiapplication

I'm trying to add a button to quickly access the iCloud Keychain. I'm aware that it isn't allowed on the App Store, that is fine.

Based on [this](https://medium.com/@contact.jmeyers/complete-list-of-ios-url-schemes-for-apple-settings-always-updated-20871139d72f) article I found the preferred deep link for iOS Settings > Passwords,
`prefs:root=PASSWORDS&search=$query`. I added the `prefs` value to my "Queried URL Schemes" in `info.plist` as well.

Despite this, the app fails to open my URL and throws this error:

```
Failed to open URL prefs:root=PASSWORDS: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=244, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}
```

This error is given when omitting the "search" parameter too.

Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "isn't allowed on the App Store", you mean Apple states this isn't allowed on published apps (**and** you don't plan to submit this), you just want to do it for some other form of distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Apple changes the Settings app scheme names, paths, parameters etc. very often. While some older versions of the Settings app support `prefs:` scheme, new ones support `App-prefs:` so in your case for opening the Settings Passwords you should try the latter:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "App-prefs:PASSWORDS&search=your-domain.com")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Also you can use a more generic solution in order to support all known schemes:

```swift
func openSettings(path: String) {
    let schemes = [
        "App-prefs:",
        "App-prefs:root=",
        "prefs:",
        "prefs:root=",
    ]
    
    for scheme in schemes {
        let url = URL(string: "\(scheme)\(path)")!
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            break
        }
    }
}

openSettings(path: "PASSWORDS&search=your-domain.com")
```

Comment: FYI - The scheme of a URL is the part up to but not including the colon. So `App-prefs` is the scheme. The `root=` part is part of the query parameters, not any part of the scheme.